Spring OAuth2 flow with azure-ad
Current setup:

Frontend (Angular)
Reverse Proxy (Nginx)
BFF (Spring Gateway & Spring OAuth2 Client)
IDP (Azure AD)
Resource Server (Spring Resource Server)

I'm currently stuck with the oauth2 flow with azure-ad (login.live.com).
This is how my flow currently looks:

The Problem
The probem that i now have, is that the resource server can't handle the access-token (opaque Token) since azure doesn't have a Introspect endpoint to validate the access-token (https://login.live.com/.well-known/openid-configuration).
Possible solution

One way would be, to send the id_token down the stream (to the resource server), but that shouldn't be that way if i'm not wrong.
I'm also not sure if spring is supporting that.

Create a custom jwt for the communication between the bff and resource server. (A lot of efford)

Let the BFF handle the authentication entirely (inside the same k8s cluster). Would work, but some security concerns (Request Spoofing)



As I already wrote in a comment to another answer, you should setup V2 tokens https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc#2-11

Is there any documentation? Version 2 wasl already set "requestedAccessTokenVersion". Created a new scope under Exposed an API. And add the new scope in the authorization request. I still get a opaque token

That's the Magic with Microsoft: there is plenty of documents, but you never now which one is up to date / applies to your use case. To put together the information I linked, it took 1.5 month, more than a dozen email to the support, and I figured out most of the information by myself browsing tons of docs. So, if you have a custom scope for your API, be sure to disable any hybrid flow, and V2 tokens, but still get opaque tokens, good luck...

Any update on the issue @MatKollin?

Unfor. not. I've created a thread here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2124699/login-live-opaque-access-token. My approch now is to not use a resource server at all. The bff is explosed to the public network and forwards to the services in the private network. Since the api's are not reachable from the public network, it's okey to not have any authentication there. Also i extract the current id of the authenticated user in the bff and also forward it directly
